# building tensorboard from source

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard, bazel

I built Tensorflow from source and built Tensorboard via 
bazel build tensorflow/contrib/tensorboard:tensorboard

The build process finished but there is no tensorboard folder in 
./bazel-bin/tensorflow or ./bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib

any ideas how to find the binary so i can run 
./bazel-bin/tensorflow/contrib/tensorboard/tensorboard --logdir=path/to/logs
?

OS: Ubuntu 16.04
Tensorflow for Python3 with GPU support
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Tensorboard is in [its own repository](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard) now.  Try:

```
git clone https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard
cd tensorboard
bazel build //tensorboard
...
Target //tensorboard:tensorboard up-to-date:
  bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard
INFO: Elapsed time: 87.181s, Critical Path: 50.59s
```

Then you can find it at `bazel-bin/tensorboard/tensorboard`.

Comment: I tried that, but some scripts inside are forced to run in Python2 and can therefore not find tensorflow.

Comment: Please add the error you're getting to your question.  Are you using a virtualenv?